# How to get real value of nVarchar in hbernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have a nvarchar column in my table, value is looking like Japanese+integers. i want to get the original value of this column by using hibernate. Is any way available to achieve this?

I tried using @Nationalized annotation on my variable, But no luck.

Comment: I actually have no idea what you mean here. *"looks like Japanese+integers"*? If it looks like kanji characters and numerics then that's what was inserted into it; hibernate won't change that.

Comment: actually it is encoded string. original data encoded into these chars

Comment: So then you need to decode it; we can't tell you how to do that, we don't know your encode algorithm,